# Is this Partition affirmation correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

This is the sentence.

If {$A_i$}$_i$$_∈$$_\mathbb{Z}$ is a partition of $\mathbb{R}$ then {$\sqrt{2}$} $⊆ A_i$ for one and only one value of $i$.

I guess it's true, because each partition differs from one another.
Is this Partition affirmation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true, since in each partition, (1) the sets $A_i$ are nonempty, (2) their union is the ambient set $\Bbb R$, and (3) two sets are either equal or disjoint.

Condition 2) ensures that $\sqrt 2\in\Bbb R$ lies in one of the sets $A_i$, and condition 3) shows that the set $A_i$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: The sentence is true or false, depending on how you define partitions; with the definition @Wuestenfux gives, it's false.  By that definition, $\{(-|i| - 1,-|i|] \cup [|i|,|i| + 1)\}_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is a partition, and $\sqrt{2} \in A_{-1}$ and $\sqrt{2} \in A_1$, and the sentence is false.  To make it true, you need to change Wuestenfux's condition (3), from "either $A_i = A_j$ or $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$", to "either $i = j$ or $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$".